# awk to remove duplicates in specific lines based on keyword in field

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to remove duplicate lines in a `tab-delimited` file if they have the  `$2` value is `Fusion` and the same `$4` value is in each line. In the example below, lines 1 and 2 have the same `$2` value and there `$4` value is also the same, so the duplicate line 2 is removed. Line 3 and four also follow this logic. The amount of lines may be variable, but the format will be the same.  Since lines 5 and 6 do not have `Fusion` in `$2` they are skipped and printed in output. Thank you :).

**file**

```
chr12:12006495-chr15:88483984 Fusion Gain-of-Function ETV6NTRK3-E4N15 1868
chr15:88483984-chr12:12006495 Fusion Gain-of-Function ETV6NTRK3-E4N15 1868
chr12:12022903-chr15:88483984 Fusion Gain-of-Function ETV6NTRK3-E5N15 414833
chr15:88483984-chr12:12022903 Fusion Gain-of-Function ETV6NTRK3-E5N15 414833
chr10     SNV     ....
chr15     SNV     ....
```

**awk**

```
awk -F'\t' '{if($2 in a)a[$2]=$2=="Fusion"?$0:a[$4];else a[$4]=$0}END{for(i in a)print a[i]}' file
```

**desired output**

```
chr12:12006495-chr15:88483984 Fusion Gain-of-Function ETV6NTRK3-E4N15 1868
chr12:12022903-chr15:88483984 Fusion Gain-of-Function ETV6NTRK3-E5N15 414833
chr10     SNV     ....
chr15     SNV     ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F'\t' '!($2 == "Fusion" && seen[$4]++)' file
```

- `$2 == "Fusion" && seen[$4]++` matches lines whose 2nd field is equal to `Fusion` and whose 4th field has been seen at least once before.

  - `seen[$4]++` is a common Awk idiom that incrementally builds an associative array of field values by adding entries on demand and recording the occurrence count of each value. The *post*-decrement (`...++`) ensures that on encountering a given value for the *first* time `seen[$4]++` evaluates to (conceptual) *false*, whereas all subsequent occurrences imply *true*.
- `!(...)` negates the logic, evaluating to (conceptual) *true* only if:

  - the 2nd field does *not* equal `Fusion`
  - *or* the 4th field value is being seen for the *first* time.
- The whole `!(...)` expression is a *pattern* in Awk terminology, and a pattern that has no associated *action* (a `{ ... }` block) defaults to *printing* the input record at hand
  (action `{ print }` is implied).

<sup>Tip of the hat to [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton) for his help.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for me:

```
awk -F'\t' '{if($2 == "FUSION")a[$4] = $0; else b[$0]=$0;}END{for(k in a)print a[k];for(l in b)print b[l];}' file
```

The only issue is that it reorders things so that all the `$2 == "FUSION"` cases come first.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and explanations :)